# Performing a reaction on one side of piperazine ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemoselectivity, protecting-groups

I want to perform a reaction on one nitrogen of piperazine ring while avoiding the reaction on both nitrogens, I am familiar with Boc piperazine however it's expensive and would take 2-3 months to import to my country, does anyone know an alternative method ?

Answer (score 2):

Making your own BOC piperazine is not hard, the general principle is to do the reaction with the monohydrochloride - there is a good procedure [here](http://www.rsc.org/suppdata/gc/c1/c1gc16314k/c1gc16314k.pdf) from piperazine, piperazine di-HCl, t-BuOH and carbonyl di-imidazole.

The same document also has a procedure for the monoacylation of piperazine.

A different procedure, which is general for di-amines, using Me3SiCl/SOCl2 to create the mono-hydrochloride and then reacting with BOC2O is [here](http://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1870-249X2017000100023)